# how to increment an integer in sql c#

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

I am making a voting system. I have a problem adding a count(increment each time the candidate is voted) to each candidate that they voted.

My Vote Button code is :

```
    sc.Open();
        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE TableVote SET Vcount=Vcount+1 WHERE id=@count", sc);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@count", TxtPresID.Text);

            int res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (res > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(TxtPresID.Text.ToString() + " Saved!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            sc.Close();
        }
```

and my table is

[image: my sql]

the result of `Vcount` is just `NULL`..

[image: null]

What am i doing wrong? or is my Sql statement correct?

Comment: try  `Vcount=ISNULL(Vcount,0)+1`

Comment: Do not allow Null to Vcount

Comment: Don't allow `NULL` at all. Something that doesn't have any votes against it would have a vote count of **0**, not `null`!

Comment: What "result" do you mean - in the table, or are you trying to pull the new vote count back to the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the default Value of `Vcount` to be 0. It shouldn't be a null column.

Here is the query

```
ALTER TABLE {TABLENAME} 
ADD {COLUMNNAME} {TYPE} {NULL|NOT NULL} 
CONSTRAINT {CONSTRAINT_NAME} DEFAULT {DEFAULT_VALUE}

ALTER TABLE TableVote 
ADD Vcount int NOT NULL 
CONSTRAINT  tablevote_vcount_default DEFAULT 0
```

Another option is to check, whether Vcount is NULL

```
UPDATE TableVote SET Vcount=ISNULL(Vcount, 0) + 1 WHERE id=@count
```

Comment: Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'Vcount' in table 'TableVote' is specified more than once.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like your `Vcount` is `NULL`. As others have pointed out, you should make that column default to `0` or you could do this

```
UPDATE TableVote SET Vcount=ISNULL(Vcount, 0) + 1 WHERE id=@count
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be updating the count row every time. if you have 2 votes incoming at the same time, it might have unpredictable consequences.

A better way would be to have a table "votes" and then insert a row for every vote, including the candidate ID, the voter ID and the date of vote. also means you can have historical data for different voters, and that you can easily change votes if needed.

Comment: This is a very good point, so I'll give it a +1, but it does not answer the question.

Comment: It does not answer the question, but I think it is a very valid point. Nice catch. +1

Answer (score 2):

Learn that

```
Null + 1 = Null
```

So your Vcount will always be null when adding 1.
Vcount must be not nullable, and it's default value muste be 0. Then when you will add 1 to 0, it will give you the good result.

Answer (score 1):

You can also Change your SQL Statement so that zero is used if the VCOUNT-Column is null:

```
"UPDATE TableVote SET Vcount=ISNULL(Vcount, 0)+1 WHERE id=@count"
```

This is especially useful if you cannot change the database schema to be Not-Null and have a Default value.

Answer (score 1):

Vcount must be have a default 0 value, and Not Null, cause is an Int Field.

Answer (score 1):

If i am not wrong why not just use your primary key for it ,

```
UPDATE TableVote SET Vcount= max(id)  WHERE id=@count
```

OR

If some id's are deleted and you don't want to keep records or count deleted votes then

```
  UPDATE TableVote SET Vcount= COUNT(id)  WHERE id=@count
```